# Exception: The data validation rule has more items than the limit of 500. Use the "List from a range" criteria instead

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google sheet for Competitor backlink Audit. In previous, it was work perfectly. Last day I tried to use my sheet again and this time, it's not worked. It shows the message

> Exception: The data validation rule has more items than the limit of
> 500.Use the "List from a range" criteria instead.

This sheet is working 4 step way.

1. merging various data using an app script, and it worked perfectly.
2. filtered merging data using various filter data.
3. create a data validation, and this step is not worked.
4. dependent on the 3rd step. So this also not worked.

I tried to fix this, but I can't figure it out.

Here is my sheet URL:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1T2Jsni659wK3m9ZDka875d8wIoNrxYYn55SaKsjPGrc/edit#gid=1602455067
Also, the Code is too long to share

1st URL is the main code set: https://pastebin.pl/view/4f445433

2nd URL is the helper of 1st code: https://pastebin.pl/view/99ccc65e

custom menu here
[image: custom menu here]

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says:

### You are trying to add too many options to the Dropdown.

If there are more than 500 rows in the sheet which your script tries to use as data validation options - the script will error.

**Solution:**

Do not use more than 500 options.

You have more values than this - try to break them down into a nested Dropdown e.g. into Main Categories and Sub categories.

Since you do not provide your script or public access to your spreadsheet, I can not give you more details, but make sure that your script does not try to assign more than 500 values for data validation.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply and also the way I shared. I update the file permission

Here is my sheet URL: 
[https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1T2Jsni659wK3m9ZDka875d8wIoNrxYYn55SaKsjPGrc/edit#gid=1602455067](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1T2Jsni659wK3m9ZDka875d8wIoNrxYYn55SaKsjPGrc/edit#gid=1602455067)
Also, the Code is too long to share

1st URL is the main code set: [https://pastebin.pl/view/4f445433](https://pastebin.pl/view/4f445433)
2nd URL is the helper of 1st code: [https://pastebin.pl/view/99ccc65e](https://pastebin.pl/view/99ccc65e)

Comment: You need to debug your code stepwise. 1. If you run the functions from the Apps script editor instead of the Sheets UI - you will see which function gives you the error - it"s `populateSummaryTab()`. 2. You will see a more detailled error message: `Exception: The data validation rule has more items than the limit of 500. Use the ‘List from a range’ criteria instead. at filterSummaryData(helpers:336:73)     at populateSummaryTab(Code:318:5)` If you log `Logger.log(linkTypeNames.length);`, you will see that the array has 3362 entries while only 500 are allowed!

Comment: This is why `summarySheet.getRange(dataTableStartRow - 1, anchorTypeTableStartColumn + 1, 1, 1).setDataValidation(linkTypeRule);` gives you an error. So please investigate why this array is so long and find a way to reduce it to max. 500 elements!